Rendering problem on v-data-table headers and checkbox completion
The problem i am having today is that first : the headers of my v-data-table are not visible , and the second one is that the v-checkbox provided by the props in the v-data-table. When the first v-checkbox in the headers row is selected , all the rows should be selected. This is ok , but when i selet any other row, all the checkboxes are automatically checked . What should i do to make it work ?
<template >
    <div class="bg-grey-darken-4">
      <p class="font-weight-light h3 text-center p-2 ">Produse</p>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
  
      <!-- File Upload and Buttons -->
      <v-container class="text-center mt-4">
        <v-file-input
          ref="fileInput"
          accept=".xlsx"
          v-model="productsExcel"
          style="display: none;"
          @change="importExcel"
        ></v-file-input>
  
        <!-- Alerts -->
        <v-alert v-if="fileError" type="error" dismissible class="m-3" closable>
          {{ fileErrorMessage }}
        </v-alert>
  
        <v-alert v-if="waitForParsing" type="info" dismissible class="m-3" closable>
          {{ waitForParsingText }}
        </v-alert>
  
        <v-alert v-if="succesWhenParsing" type="success" dismissible class="m-3" closable>
          {{ succesWhenParsingText }}
        </v-alert>
  
        <v-alert v-if="errorWhenParsing" type="error" dismissible class="m-3" closable>
          {{ errorWhenParsingText }}
        </v-alert>
  
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <v-btn rounded color="success" class="mr-2" @click="triggerFileInput">
          Importa Excel
          <v-icon right>mdi-file-upload</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
  
        <v-btn rounded color="primary" @click="redirectToAddingProduct">
          Adauga Produs
          <v-icon right>mdi-plus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </v-container>
  
      <v-divider class="my-4"></v-divider>
  
      <!-- Search Field -->
      <!-- Error and Empty Alerts -->
      <div class="p-3">
        <v-alert v-if="errorOnLoadingProducts" type="error" dismissible class="mt-2">
          {{ errorOnLoadingProductsText }}
        </v-alert>
  
        <v-alert v-else-if="emptyProducts" type="warning" dismissible class="mt-2">
          {{ emptyProductsText }}
        </v-alert>
  
        <!-- Data Table -->
        <v-card v-else
        class="bg-blue-grey-darken-4 rounded-xl "
         >
            <v-card-title class="text-center">
                Produse
            </v-card-title>
            <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            label="Cauta"
            prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
            class="p-3 mx-3"
            variant="outlined"
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-data-table
                :headers="headers"
                :items="filteredProducts"
                :items-per-page="15"
                item-key="codProdusAdminDto"
                v-model="selectedProducts"
                show-select
                class=" bg-blue-grey-darken-4"
            >
            <!-- Custom Actions for Each Row -->
                
                <template #[`item.actions`]="{ item }">
                    <v-icon
                        color="primary"
                        size="28"
                        class="mr-2"
                        @click="seeProductPage(item.codProdusAdminDto)"
                        >
                        mdi-eye
                    </v-icon>
                    <v-icon
                        color="error"
                        size="28"
                        @click="deleteProduct(item.codProdusAdminDto)"
                        >
                        mdi-delete
                    </v-icon>
                </template>
        
                <!-- Custom Categories Display -->
                <template #[`item.categoriiProdusDto`]="{ item }">
                    {{ item.categoriiProdusDto?.join(', ') || 'No Categories' }}
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>
  


<script>
import adminService from '@/services/Admin'

export default {
  name: 'AdminProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      productsExcel: null,
      fileError: false,
      fileErrorMessage: 'Extensia incorecta! Extensia trebuie sa fie .xlsx',
      waitForParsing: false,
      waitForParsingText: 'Asteptati pentru citirea fisierului excel...',
      emptyProducts: false,
      emptyProductsText: 'Nu aveti produse adaugate',
      errorOnLoadingProducts: false,
      errorOnLoadingProductsText: 'O eroare a avut loc!',
      succesWhenParsing: false,
      succesWhenParsingText: 'Fisierul a fost procesat cu succes!',
      errorWhenParsing: false,
      errorWhenParsingText: 'O eroare a avut loc la parsarea fisierului',
      products: [],
      selectedProducts: [],
      headers: [
        { text: 'Cod produs', value: 'codProdusAdminDto', align: 'center' },
        { text: 'Nume produs', value: 'numeProdusAdminDto', align: 'center' },
        { text: 'Tip produs', value: 'tipProdusDto', align: 'center' },
        { text: 'Categoriile produsului', value: 'categoriiProdusDto', align: 'center' },
        { text: 'Actiuni', value: 'actions', align: 'center', sortable: false },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredProducts() {
      if (!this.search) return this.products;
      const searchTerm = this.search.toLowerCase();
      return this.products.filter(product => {
        return (
          product.codProdusAdminDto.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          product.numeProdusAdminDto.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          product.tipProdusDto.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          product.categoriiProdusDto.some(cat => cat.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
        );
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getProducts();
  },
  methods: {
    async getProducts() {
        try {
            const response = await adminService.getProductsForAdminPage();
            if (response === -1) {
            this.errorOnLoadingProducts = true;
            } else if (response === -2) {
            this.$router.push('/logout');
            } else if (response.length === 0) {
            this.emptyProducts = true;
            } else {
            this.products = response.map(product => ({
                ...product,
                categoriiProdusDto: product.categoriiProdusDto || [],
            }));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
            this.errorOnLoadingProducts = true;
        }
    },

    triggerFileInput() {
      this.$refs.fileInput.click();
    },
    async importExcel() {
      if (!this.productsExcel) {
        this.fileError = true;
        return;
      }
      this.waitForParsing = true;
      try {
        const response = await adminService.uploadXlsxFile(this.productsExcel);
        if (response === 1) {
          this.succesWhenParsing = true;
          this.waitForParsing = false
         
          return
        } else {
          this.errorWhenParsing = true;
          this.waitForParsing = false
         
          return
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error importing Excel file:', error);
        this.errorWhenParsing = true;
        this.waitForParsing = false;
      } finally {
        this.waitForParsing = false;
        this.productsExcel = null; // Reset file input
      }
    },
    seeProductPage(productCode) {
      this.$router.push(`/product/${productCode}`);
    },
    async deleteProduct(productCode) {
     console.log(productCode)
    },
    redirectToAddingProduct() {
    
    },
  },
};
</script>




If this is Vuetify 3, you need to use item-value, not item-key (that's Vuetify 2). I don't understand what problem you have with the header. Consider sharing a playgfound where the issue can be inspected.

Are you using vueitfy2 or vuetify3?

i am using vuetify 3

https://pastebin.com/TasiL7Aq i could not share the playground because the link is too long . here is a paste bin. !!!EDIT: The problem with the checkbox has been solved , thanks EDIT!!!.

SOLVED! In my headers array i had text instead of title . Now it works!

ANSWER!

Instead of item-key i used item-value which solved the checkbox problem
Instead of text prop in my headers array i used title

